# How to change the shape of the marker depending on a column variable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, markers

I am trying to create a scatter plot for a csv file in python which contains 4 columns `x`, `y`, `TL`, `L`. I am supposed to plot `x` versus `y` and change the color of the marker based on the `class ID` in the `TL` column which I have achieved in the below code.

```
import pandas as pd    
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv('knnDataSet.csv')  
df.columns=['SN','x','y','TL','L']

color=['red','green','blue']

groups = df.groupby('TL')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for name, group in groups:    
    ax.plot(group.x, group.y, marker='o', linestyle='', ms=12, label=name)

ax.legend()    
plt.show()
```

Also, I need to  change the shape depending on whether the marker has a label in the `L` column or not, but I dont know how to update my code to fit this requirement.

Here is the link for the `knnDataSet.csv` file:
[*knnDataSet.csv*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9fzjs1pkmhyzqw/knnDataSet.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Here is the link for the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9fzjs1pkmhyzqw/knnDataSet.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv('knnDataSet.csv')
df.columns=['SN','x','y','TL','L']
color=['red','green','blue']

groups = df.groupby('TL')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,8))

for name, group in groups:   
    for x in group.values:
        if np.isnan(x[4]):
            ax.plot(x[1], x[2], marker='x', linestyle='', ms=12)
        else:
            ax.plot(x[1], x[2], marker='o', linestyle='', ms=12)                       

#ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

If a label in the L column is **NOT** defined then the marker will be `X`
If a label in the L column **IS** defined then the marker will be `O`

**Output:**
[image]