# How to plot the fourth variable based on a given x, y and z coordinate framework

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 4d

I have a numpy array with four columns and several rows. First column is my variable and three others are `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates, respectivly:

```
arr= np.array([[2., 0., 0., 0.],
               [1., 0., 0., 1.],
               [2., 0., 1., 0.],
               [3., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

The first column has some discrete values, e.g. it is `1` or `2` or `3`. Now, using matplotlib or any other useful library like seaborn) I want to plot these values in a 3d space created by the second, third and fourth column. For example, I want to represent `1` as red star symbols, `2` as a yellow rectangles and `3` as black squares. I do appreciate if any one help me to do so. I tried the following code but it did not give me what I want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
x= arr[0][:,1]
y= arr[0][:,2]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z= arr[0][:,3]
V= arr[0][:,0]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.view_init(45,60)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, z, facecolors=cm.Oranges(V))
```

I want to have the automatic version of the following figure:

[image]

Comment: I know why got the idea but you don't want to plot a surface. [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31575664/8881141) Since `marker` does not accept an array as input, you have to [group your data before plotting.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39694347/8881141)

Comment: Dear @Mr. T, Thanks for the help, that’s what I wanted. But, do you think there is a way to personalize the data visualization  rather than representing them with cmap?

Comment: See the comment update regarding marker shapes. Marker sizes would be different - the size could be directly provided as an array to matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scatter plots lead to your expected output and can easily be individualized. This example code should even work for more than just 3 cases (as long as you add marker styles and colors)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

arr= np.array([[2., 0., 0., 0.],
               [1., 0., 0., 1.],
               [2., 0., 1., 0.],
               [3., 1., 0., 0.]])


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

arr_T = arr.T

#get unique values --> makes it possible to work with more cases, may not be necessary
unique = list(set(arr_T[0]))
marker_styles = {1:"*", 2:"s", 3:"o"}
marker_colors = {1:"r", 2:"y", 3:"black"}
for i in range(len(unique)):
    value = unique[i]
    xs = arr[arr_T[0] == value].T[1]
    ys = arr[arr_T[0] == value].T[2]
    zs = arr[arr_T[0] == value].T[3]
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, marker=marker_styles[unique[i]], color = marker_colors[unique[i]], alpha=1)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

ax.view_init(45,60)
plt.show()
```