# Improve My `matplotlib.pyplot` Syntax for Scatter Plot by Target

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have three dimensional data, where one dimension is categorical: `length`, `width`, `target`. For simplicity, say that `target` can take values in `{0, 1, 2}`. I would like to plot `length` vs `width` "by" `target`. The points will have different colours and shapes depending on the target value.

I am able to do this in `matplotlib.pyplot`, imported as `plt`, using the following syntax. I assume that a `pandas` `DataFrame` `df` has the structure I imposed.

```
X0 = df.query("target == 0.0").drop("target", axis = 1)
X1 = df.query("target == 1.0").drop("target", axis = 1)
X2 = df.query("target == 2.0").drop("target", axis = 1)

ax = plt.axes()
X0.plot(x = "length", y = "width", kind = "scatter", ax = ax, color = "red")
X1.plot(x = "length", y = "width", kind = "scatter", ax = ax, color = "blue")
X2.plot(x = "length", y = "width", kind = "scatter", ax = ax, color = "green")
plt.show()
```

I'm sure that we can all agree that this is *bbaaaddd*.

A few years ago, I used to do some programming in `R`. The `ggplot2` package allowed a syntax of the form

```
ggplot(df, x = length, y = width, shape = target).geom_point().
```

One could replace `shape = target` with `colour = target` to get different colours depending on the value of `target`.

I would like something similar in `pyplot`. Try as I might, I have not been able to find such information in documentation or online sources. I'm sure it must be out there *somewhere*. I just have not been able to find it...

---

**Edit.**
This question was marked as a duplicate. The duplicates were helpful in solving some of the issues, but they do not resolve all the questions raised above. In particular, shapes are not discussed. The closest that I have found is the following question: [How to change the shape of the marker depending on a column variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692554/how-to-change-the-shape-of-the-marker-depending-on-a-column-variable). There are other similar questions. But this is pretty ugly compared with a simple `shape = "target"` call.

There is a "ggplot for python" package, called `plotnine`, but it doesn't *seem* to have been updated for 5 years. You also *seem* to need do stuff like `from plotnine import *`, which I'm certainly not excited by.

Maybe the functionality I'm after just doesn't exist in `pyplot`. If so, such is life! :)

---

**Edit.** @Trenton McKinney suggests using `seaborn`, imported as `sns`. This has a `hue` option, which does precisely the different colouring.

```
sns.scatterplot(data = df, x = "length", y = "width", hue = "target")
```

This still doesn't answer my question about shapes---neither did the (partial) "duplicates". However, `sns.scatterplot` also has a `style` option, which has the same description as `hue` except "different colours" is replaced by "different markers".

```
sns.scatterplot(data = df, x = "length", y = "width", style = "target")
```

Why not go crazy and use both `hue` and `style`!

I guess that the correct answer is "don't do it in `matplotlib`; do it in `seaborn`". Hopefully the incorrect marking as duplicate will be resolved, then I can add an answer with the full details.

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
for target in [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]:
    df.query("target == " + str(target)).drop("target", axis = 1).plot(x = 
        "length", y = "width", kind = "scatter")
plt.show()
```